# Uploading TAB data to MSSQL using ogr2ogr

Tags: sql-server, ogr2ogr

I have been trying various methods to import a shapefile into MSSQL but keep getting

FAILURE: no source datasource provided.

ATTEMPTS

1. `ogr2ogr -f "MSSQL:Server=xxx;Database=_GIS_Test;UID=yyy;PWD=zzz"  -nln “D:\QGIS_Development\mssql\bridges.shp” “MGM_Bridges_test” a_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:28354 -nln “MGM_Bridges_test”`
2. CD to folder and

   ```
   ogr2ogr -overwrite -f “MSSQLSpatial” “MSSQL:Server=z;Database=_GIS_Test;UID=xxx;PWD=yyy"  bridges.shp a_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:28354 -nln “MGM_Bridges_test”
   ```

3.

```
ogr2ogr -overwrite -f “MSSQLSpatial” “MSSQL:Server=z;Database=_GIS_Test;UID=xxx;PWD=yyy" a_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:28354 -nln bridges.shp “MGM_Bridges_test”
```

ogrinfo on the input dataset opens it.

I have checked many posts here but no one reports this issue. Tried bridges.shp in quotes. I have removed the "“MGM_Bridges_test”" and I get the error No Target Datasource provided.

---- UPDATE

I tried typing the following but still get the same error...
[image]

**ANOTHER attempt -same issue**
[image]

Comment: thanks -there seems to be 2 here. I tried typing it in and I get no datasource provided. This is for the command I added to the question.

Comment: Please read cafefully the manual pages of ogr2ogr and MSSQL and check your command. At least you have not defined the outputformat, -f should be followed by the driver name `-f MSSQLSpatial` https://www.gdal.org/drv_mssqlspatial.html. Do you really want to create a layer named "bridges.shp" as you now do with your -nln? -a_srs and -t_srs are not supposed to be used together.

Comment: Thanks - as in my ex. 3 in the original question, I have tried this as well. ogr2ogr -overwrite -f “MSSQLSpatial” “MSSQL:Server=z;Database=_GIS_Test;UID=xxx;PWD=yyy" -a_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:28354 -nln bridges.shp “MGM_Bridges_test” . Note I have tried this without  -a_srs EPSG:4326 as well. Based on the answer in https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/171005/esri-shapefile-not-loading-into-sql-server?rq=1

Comment: To clarify - I have tried this as well (ex. 3 in my q).Note I have tried this without  -a_srs EPSG:4326 as well. Based on the answer in https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/171005/esri-shapefile-not-loading-into-sql-server?rq=1 and also D:\QGIS_Development\George\mssql>ogr2ogr -overwrite -f "MSSQLSpatial" "MSSQL:Ser
ver=xxx;Database=_GIS_Test;UID=xxx;PWD=yyyy" bridges.shp -a_srs "EPSG:28354" -nln "MGM_Bridges_test"

Comment: This last command looks good, but I have no own experience on MSSQL. What is the error now? Adding `--debug on` to your command may give more information.

Comment: @user30184 still pretty much the same. I have added screen grab also showing the datasource does exist and is ogr compatible

Comment: you have some options after `src_dataset_name` that are shown in the usage to be expected before. Try ordering these arguments in the way shown in the usage.

Comment: @MikeT thanks -which expected usage? I have tried the options from the main help and also from variations in multiple posts. ex. the input file after the server definition and after the -nln as well.

Comment: the screenshots above show the order of expected commands in their usage.. follow this order. Also try to use regular quotes `"x"` rather than fancy quotes `“x”`.

Comment: @MikeT that worked. I have put in as an answer but happy to accept yours if you want to add one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Mike T - it works when formatted exactly as per the help file and not based on the options order that's worked for other people.

```
ogr2ogr -overwrite -f "MSSQLSpatial" "MSSQL:Server=zzz;Database=NGSC_GIS_Test;UID=xx;PWD=yyy" bridges.shp -a_srs "EPSG:28354" -nln "MGM_Bridges_test"
```